# How to determine the type of a mobile application

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to automate an application on an Android device but I am having a problem. When the application is launched and running on my device, I can see it properly, using the UIAutomatorViewer but it looks like the elements in the application haven't been detected properly by it. So if I want to interact with an element, the only option for me now is to manually determine its physical location and use `tap` there. This is obviously not the best approach.

After doing some reading online I learned that UIAutomatorViewer only supposed to work with Native applications while I am not 100% sure what type of application is the one that I am working with. I have tried to inspect it via Chrome `chrome://inspect/#devices` and the application is definitely displayed there with all the elements I need. I am not sure however that this is an indication of being a web app or hybrid app?

I have also tried to view the context handlers:

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
    System.out.println(contextNames);
}
```

But it only prints out `NATIVE_APP` context which doesn't sum up with my theory that this might be a web or hybrid app and that's the reason why I can't use UIAutomatorViewer properly.

Comment: if `chrome://inspect/#devices` displays it. It certainly has a webview or else it wouldn't be displayed to what I have tried on my app. Moreover I am curious to know if you are getting the contexts using the above code on the same View?

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid app - embeded HTML5 apps inside a thin native container. Then, if some menu/views of your native application contains WebView - app is hybrid. So, to say that is not hybrid app on all menu/views should be only one context. You can try to search by class (e.g. android - "android.webkit.WebView") or to check contexts on each application view. And if app is hybrid you can switch between contexts and find elements for example in web context by css selectors.